# Group by multiple columns and then collect the list - Hive

Tags: hive

I have two tables namely posts and tags.

```
posts:
account_id post_id
1 1
1 2
2 2
2 3
2 5
3 4

tags:
account_id post_id tag_id
1 1 21
1 2 22
1 2 26
2 2 28
2 3 23
2 3 24
2 3 25
2 5 27
```

Now to get the all the tags assosiated with posts at an account level i have performed the following join.

```
CREATE TABLE posts_tags1
AS
SELECT a.account_id, a.post_id, b.tag_id FROM posts a LEFT OUTER JOIN tags b ON a.account_id = b.account_id AND a.post_id = b.post_id;
```

And the result that i have got is:

```
posts_tags1:
account_id post_id tag_id
1 1 21
1 2 22
1 2 26
2 2 28
2 3 23
2 3 24
2 3 25
2 5 27
3 4 NULL
```

Now i would like to convert the above result into

```
post_tags:
account_id post_id tag_ids
1 1 [21]
1 2 [22,26]
2 2 [28]
2 3 [23,24,25]
2 5 [27]
3 4 []
```

Can any one help me to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
CREATE TABLE post_tags 
AS 
SELECT account_id, post_id, collect_list(tag_id) FROM posts_tags GROUP BY account_id, post_id;
```